# Fixed scrolling on a div

Tags: html, css, scroll

Im in the process of updating my portfolio, and wanted to try and achieve the effect done on this website http://matthias.webrom.fr/, where the landing page itself doesn't scroll but the content slides over it. It is the same effect you would get with a background if you put `background-attachment: fixed` on it. Is there a way to achieve the same effect on a div using just CSS?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [div image position fixed + scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721502/div-image-position-fixed-scroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website http://matthias.webrom.fr/ is composed of two main sections, the header and the page_content. The header contains the front page with the effect that you want to replicate and the page_content contains the rest of the website. This is easy to see using the Developer Tools (in chrome go to View->Developer->Developer Tools), this tool is very useful! (I recommend that you learn how to use it)

If you look at the header CSS you'll see that:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

This forces the background to stay in the same position (thus not scrolling with the rest of the content). However this only applies to the background image. Inside the header there is a section element that contains the text. The section position is set to:

```
position: fixed;
```

This forces the text to remain in the same position because it is being positioned relative to the browser window not the document flow.

Now in order for the header to appear behind the page_content you'll have to play with the z-index. You want the header to be behind everything else, so it has to have a lower z-index than the page_content.